# Регулярное выражение для нахождения числа целиком

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть вот такая строка:

```
5(70);15(75);5(57)
```

в формате `key(value);key(value);key(value)`.

Необходимо получить все значения (value) с ключом (key) 5.
Вот регулярное выражение, которое я использую для этого:

```
(?<=^5\()\d+(?=\))|(?<=[^0-9]5\()\d+(?=\))
```

и его [результат](https://regex101.com/r/OvVwkC/1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, все работает. Но я уверен, что данное регулярное выражение можно оптимизировать. Помогите это сделать, если конечно его действительно стоит оптимизировать.

Comment: во второй половине можно `;` использовать, а не `[^0-9]` то есть либо `^5` либо `;5`

Answer (score 1):

Для php есть вариант такой:

```
(?:^|;)5\(\K[^)]+
```

Ответ в нулевой группе.

Тест https://regex101.com/r/hamf1f/1

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте модификатор границы слова `\b` и признак нежадного модификатора `+?` и все станет проще

```
(?<=\b5\()(\d+?)(?=\))
```

[RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/OvVwkC/2)

Или убрать пре и пост просмотр (быстрее будет работать)

```
\b5\((\d+?)\)
```

и искать результат в первой группе

Или, учитывая то, что у Вас в скобках бывают только цифры, можно забить на проверку наличия завершающей `)`

```
(?<=\b5\()(\d+)
\b5\((\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let foo ={};
let temp;

"5(70);15(75);6(57)".split(";").forEach(item => {
 temp = item.split("(");
 foo[temp[0]] = temp[1].replace(')', '')
});

console.log(foo);
```

P.S. Начал решать проблему с помощью регулярных выражений. Теперь решаю две проблемы.